# Python minimization leastsq with columns

Tags: python, arrays, mathematical-optimization

Please excuse me but I started recently using Python...and code.
I have some troubles with optimization in python...
I would like to determine coefficients k0,k1...of a polynom defined in residual_x with data of vector "T" for each column of 2D array "test" (as example here with 3 columns), is it possible? and store results as 2D array.

As you can see, I do for only a list of data.

Thanks a lot for help!!!

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
import pylab 
from scipy.optimize import leastsq

T = np.arange(5,56,5)
T = np.reshape(T,(11,1))

test = np.array([[  3051.11,   2984.85,   3059.17],
       [  3510.78,   3442.43,   3520.7 ],
       [  4045.91,   3975.03,   4058.15],
       [  4646.37,   4575.01,   4662.29],
       [  5322.75,   5249.33,   5342.1 ],
       [  6102.73,   6025.72,   6127.86],
       [  6985.96,   6906.81,   7018.22],
       [  7979.81,   7901.04,   8021.  ],
       [  9107.18,   9021.98,   9156.44],
       [ 10364.26,  10277.02,  10423.1 ],
       [ 11776.65,  11682.76,  11843.18]])

k0 = 100.
k1 = 100.
k2 = 1.
k3 = 1.
k4 = 1.
k5 = 10.

def residual_x(vars, T, donnees):
    k0 = vars[0]
    k1 = vars[1]
    k2 = vars[2]
    k3 = vars[3]
    k4 = vars[4]
    k5 = vars[5]
    modele = T**5*k0+T**4*k1+T**3*k2+T**2*k3+T*k4+k5
    return (donnees-modele)

vars = [k0, k1, k2, k3, k4, k5]
out_x = leastsq(residual_x, vars, args=(T, test),epsfcn=0.001)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to fit three different 5th-degree polynomials with a common set of domain points, {5,10,15,...,55}, to three different range sets (the columns of `test`).

Your original code had indentation errors: from `k0 = 100.` and down was incorrectly indented; that was probably a cut-and-paste error.

More importantly, you need to fit each polynomial separately, so you should call scipy.optimize.leastsq for each column.  This is easiest to do with a for loop (see code).  You also need to collect the coefficients for each polynomial; you could do this in a 3x6 array; I've used a list in the example below.

EDIT: I was focused on getting your code working when I answered this, so I completely forgot that fitting polynomial coefficients doesn't need a non-linear solver.  You should take a look at `numpy.polyfit`, which is a convenience wrapper around a least-squares linear solver for polynomial coefficients.  You can find out more [in the numpy docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) or [at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression), and I've added sample usage of `numpy.polyfit` to the example below.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import leastsq

T = np.arange(5,56,5)

test = np.array([[  3051.11,   2984.85,   3059.17],
                 [  3510.78,   3442.43,   3520.7 ],
                 [  4045.91,   3975.03,   4058.15],
                 [  4646.37,   4575.01,   4662.29],
                 [  5322.75,   5249.33,   5342.1 ],
                 [  6102.73,   6025.72,   6127.86],
                 [  6985.96,   6906.81,   7018.22],
                 [  7979.81,   7901.04,   8021.  ],
                 [  9107.18,   9021.98,   9156.44],
                 [ 10364.26,  10277.02,  10423.1 ],
                 [ 11776.65,  11682.76,  11843.18]])


k0 = 100.
k1 = 100.
k2 = 1.
k3 = 1.
k4 = 1.
k5 = 10.

def residual_x(vars, T, donnees):
    k0 = vars[0]
    k1 = vars[1]
    k2 = vars[2]
    k3 = vars[3]
    k4 = vars[4]
    k5 = vars[5]
    modele = T**5*k0+T**4*k1+T**3*k2+T**2*k3+T*k4+k5
    return donnees-modele

vars = [k0, k1, k2, k3, k4, k5]
coeffs=[]

for i in range(test.shape[1]):
#EDIT: previously appended the complete output of leastsq to coeffs list
#      this is wrong; leastsq returns two outputs (i.e., a tuple)
#      and we're only really interested in the coefficients
    thiscoeffs,_=leastsq(residual_x, vars, args=(T, test[:,i]),epsfcn=0.001)
    coeffs.append(thiscoeffs)

for i in range(test.shape[1]):
    print 'poly[%d] coeffs: %s' % (i,str(coeffs[i]))

# try first example with numpy.polyfit
coeffs2 = np.polyfit(T,test[:,0],5)
print 'np.polyfit for case 0: %s',str(coeffs2)

#EDIT: this added in second edit
# if you want coeffs as an array, you could convert the list like this
coeffs_array=np.asarray(coeffs)
# or you could make coeffs a numpy array in the first place
```

This gives [EDIT: coeffs2 solution added]

```
poly[0] coeffs: (array([ -9.70769231e-07,   1.56254079e-04,   5.27449301e-03,
         1.03258957e+00,   7.62019210e+01,   2.64248394e+03]), 3)
poly[1] coeffs: (array([ -1.37025641e-06,   2.10074592e-04,   2.49477855e-03,
         1.09748240e+00,   7.51708855e+01,   2.58007182e+03]), 2)
poly[2] coeffs: (array([ -1.09435897e-06,   1.58983683e-04,   5.97712121e-03,
         1.01704522e+00,   7.67132035e+01,   2.64824061e+03]), 3)
np.polyfit for case 0: %s [ -9.70769231e-07   1.56254079e-04   5.27449301e-03   1.03258957e+00
   7.62019210e+01   2.64248394e+03]
```